# firefox addon - self.port.on conflicting with $ (jquery) .

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

In my main.js file : I configured the contentScriptFile to be script.js . Also, this script file is embedded in index.html which is a tab which will be opened using tabs.open .

I have self.port.on and jquery related things in that script file . If self.port is written on the top of other jquery things, self.port.on is working and jquery is not working . But, self.port.on is written below, jquery is working fine and self.port is not working.

The script file actually deals with the data obtained using self.port (will come only when tab opened,).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many JavaScript libraries use `$` as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`, so all functionality is available without using $. If we need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, we can return control of $ back to the other library with a call to `$.noConflict()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

This technique is especially effective in conjunction with the .ready() method's ability to alias the jQuery object, as within callback passed to .ready() we can use $ if we wish without fear of conflicts later:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
    $("div").hide();
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
  $("content").style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

Source: [**jQuery.noConflict**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 1):

What about wrap all your jQuery code in a safe environment?

Using $:

```
(function($) {
    // use $
})(jQuery)
```

Using $jq:

```
(function($jq) {
    // use $jq
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's noConflict setting.

```
$jq = jQuery.noConflict(); //use $jq instead of $
```